# Cell of a minesweeper board does not appear Html&CSS&JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I am trying to creat a minesweeper board in Javascript, but first i tried to creat only one cell. this is my code. It was suppose to draw a cell from the 30px width and 30px height picture that i created ( cell.png ) but when i run the code i only see the canvas. What am i doing wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
 var s = {
 rows: 10, 
 col: 10,
 width: 30,
 height: 30,
};

var c;

window.onload = function(){
 
 var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
 c = canvas.getContext("2d");

  // c.fillRect(50,50,300,300);
 init();
}
 
var box;

function init(){
 
  box = new Image();
  box.src = "cell.png";

  draw();
}

function draw(){

c.clearRect(0,0,400,400);
c.drawImage(box,10,10);

}
 
</script>


</head>

<body>


<div id="controls">

</div>

<div id="game">

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">

</canvas>
  
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is because your code is not waiting for the image to load before trying to draw it. You need to wait till it is loaded then call the drawing code, this can be done from the image's onload event

```js
var s = {
  rows: 10, 
  col: 10,
  width: 30,
  height: 30,
};

var c;

window.onload = function(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  c = canvas.getContext("2d");
  init();
}

var box;

function init(){
  box = new Image();
  //onload will be called once the image has loaded
  box.onload = function(){
    //Here you call draw.
    draw();  
  };
  box.src = "http://placehold.it/30x30"; //"cell.png";  
}

function draw(){
  c.clearRect(0,0,400,400);
  c.drawImage(box,10,10);
}
```

```html
<canvas width="200" height="200" id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```